# Upgrading to pandas 0.14.0 is causing backwards compatibility problems

Tags: python, pandas

We have recently upgraded our version of pandas to 0.14.0. This has resulted in some pretty hectic backwards compatibility issues.

```
(Pdb) tab
    _default_index  age  gender  crosstab_weight
0                0    1       1                0
1                1    0       1                0
2                2    0       0                0
4                4    2       1                0
6                6    1       0                0
7                7    2       0                0
8                8    2       0                0
9                9    1       1                0
11              11    0       0                0
13              13    1       1                0
14              14    1       1                0
16              16    1       1                0
17              17    2       0                0
19              19    2       0                0
20              20    2       0                0
22              22    2       0                0
23              23    1       1                0
25              25    1       1                0
26              26    1       1                0
28              28    0       0                0
30              30    1       1                0
31              31    2       0                0
32              32    2       0                0
33              33    1       0                0
35              35    2       1                0
37              37    0       0                0
38              38    0       1                0
39              39    1       1                0


(Pdb) arr
[(u'age', 0), (u'gender', 0)]
```

where this used to work

```
 np.sum(np.all([tab[key] == value for key, value in arr]))
```

it is now throwing the following exception

```
The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Can you give some simple runnable example code that reproduces this issue?

Comment: sorry that was hella ambiguous

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was because we were using version 1.8 of numpy. Upgrading to 1.9 solved the issue. You cant do np.all on a list of Series is 1.8 but it is possible in numpy 1.9

so to solve

```
conda install numpy=1.9.0
```